# Why VALUE is NULL after inserted form in codeigniter?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

i use following the code

my controller

```
public function index() {
        $pesan['title'] = 'Poster';

        /* form validation size & paper type */
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('quantityposter', 'Quantity', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('priceposter', 'Price', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            /* view */
        } else {

            $data['size'] = $this->input->post('sizeposter');
            $data['papertype'] = $this->input->post['papertypeposter'];
            $data['quantity'] = $this->input->post['quantityposter'];
            $data['harga'] = $this->input->post['priceposter'];

            $this->poster_model->daftar($data);
            redirect(site_url('home'));
        }
    }
```

my model

```
public function daftar($data) {         $this->db->insert('poster', $data);     }
```

my form

```
<form action="<?php base_url('poster') ?>" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
            /* size poster input */
            /* paper type poster input */
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="quantityposter" class="col-sm-2">Quantity</label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" onchange="fetch_quantity(this.value);" name="quantityposter" value="<?php echo set_value('quantityposter', '1'); ?>">
                </div>
                <p><?php echo form_error('quantityposter'); ?></p>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="priceposter" class="col-sm-2">Price</label>
                <div class="col-sm-4" id="price">
                    <input type="text" name="priceposter" class="form-control" value="<?php echo "50000"; ?>">
                </div>
                <p><?php echo form_error('priceposter'); ?></p>
            </div>
            <br>
            /* submit input */

        </form>
```

i inserted data was successfull but the value is null ? why ? the value is wrong ? size poster form is working but papertype, quantity & harga is null ? why ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem is in your controller.

**After the else statement you used**

```
        $data['papertype'] = $this->input->post['papertypeposter'];
        $data['quantity'] = $this->input->post['quantityposter'];
        $data['harga'] = $this->input->post['priceposter'];
```

**I think it must be**

```
        $data['papertype'] = $this->input->post('papertypeposter');
        $data['quantity'] = $this->input->post('quantityposter');
        $data['harga'] = $this->input->post('priceposter');
```

Simply use parenthesis instead of brackets. Hope this helps!